# Proof Subset is Connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have a proof that with $A$ and $B$ as subsets of space $X$ and $A\subseteq B\subseteq \bar A$, if $A$ is connected then $B$ is connected

I'm trying to apply this proof to the subset of $\mathbb R^2$: $$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: x^2+y^2<4\}\cup\{(x,y) \in \mathbb Q^2: x^2+y^2\le 4\}$$

I can see that you can set $B= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: x^2+y^2<4\}$, $A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb Q^2: x^2+y^2< 4\}$, so $ \bar A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb Q^2: x^2+y^2\le 4\}$ so everything holds in regards to subsets, but in terms of then proving how this makes the subset above connected I'm struggling. I know the union of two connected sets is connected but I have $\bar A$ and $B$ as opposed to the $A$ and $B$ which I proved as connected in my original proof?

Just to summarise, my question is: knowing the information in the first line, how can I prove $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: x^2+y^2<4\}\cup\{(x,y) \in \mathbb Q^2: x^2+y^2\le 4\}$ is connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** Apply your lemma with
$$A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: x^2+y^2<4\}$$ $$\quad \text{and} \quad B = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: x^2+y^2<4\}\cup\{(x,y) \in \mathbb Q^2: x^2+y^2\le 4\}$$

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense, in terms of proving A is then connected - how would you go about this? My definition states a set is connected is there is no surjective continuous function mapping to $\{0,1\}$ and I can't get my head around proving that does not exist?

Comment: @ThomasL123 Have you heard about path-connectedness ?